# Parsing text file after certain word

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like to parse the following file and get the values after the "ID" and "Label":

```
{"data" : [{
    "id" : "3743",
    "fgColor" : "#000000",
    "Comment" : [ "GLIO" ],
    "Group" : "0",
    "Shape" : "roundrectangle",
    "GraphicsName" : "TITLE:Glioma",
    "Matching_Attribute" : [ "TITLE:Glioma" ],
    "Entry_id" : "78",
    "Label" : "TITLE:Glioma",
    "EntrezIDs" : "05214, ",
    "shared_name" : "path:hsa05214",
    "Type" : "map",
    "kegg_x" : "86.0",
    "kegg_y" : "58.0",
    "bgColor" : "#FFFFFF",
    "name" : "path:hsa05214",
    "SUID" : 3743,
    "Height" : "25",
    "Width" : "92",
    "Link" : "http://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?hsa05214",
    "selected" : false
  }]}
```

I'm using the following code there is nothing being written to the file specified:

```
import re
cyjs = open("/users/skylake/desktop/cyjs-example.txt", "r")
jsonfile = open("/users/skylake/desktop/jsonfile.txt", "w")
for line in cyjs:
    if line.startswith('"id"'):
        print(line)
        jsonfile.write(line)
jsonfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better suited for the problem tool.

It is a *JSON file* which can be parsed with [`json` built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
   ...:     data = json.load(f) 

In [3]: obj = data["data"][0]

In [4]: obj["id"]
Out[4]: u'3743'

In [5]: obj["Label"]
Out[5]: u'TITLE:Glioma'
```

Comment: The JSON file I have actually has about 250 "id"  and "label" tags how would I make it dynamic enough to just get all the information written into an outside file or into a list? I had another question posted about this where I want to extract the information from a CYJS file to [recreate it in actual JSON format] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754959/parsing-cyjs-file-to-convert-to-json) I'm getting an "Extra data" error.

Comment: @Quintakov you can loop over all the objects in the `data`, e.g. = `[(obj["id"], obj["Label"]) for obj in data["data"]]`.

Comment: I keep getting a " UnicodeDecodeError: "ascii" codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)".

Comment: Could you explain further?I'm somewhat new to all this.